# Excluding autoconfiguration class gives 404 not found error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, postman

I am using Spring security in my application for encrypting user password in database.
Due to this I am getting ***Using generated security password:XXXXXX*** in my Spring boot log when starting application.
I didn't want this password to be generated so I am using @SpringBootApplication (exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class }) in my main class.
***Below is my main class***

```
package com.example.policymanagementsystem;
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication (exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan( basePackages = {"com.example.policymanagementsystem.bean"})
public class PolicymanagementsystemApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PolicymanagementsystemApplication.class, args);
        }
}
```

So the password is not getting generated when starting spring boot application but when I hit api from postman it is giving me 404 Not found error for all other api's.
I don't want authentication to any of my api's so I have given below configuration in the SecurityConfiguration class.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/user/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        
http.exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(
            (request, response, ex) -> {
                response.sendError(
                    HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                    ex.getMessage()
                );
            }
        );
 http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Please suggest me some way so that I can exclude SecurityAutoConfiguration.class and not get 404 not found error in my postman response for any api.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you have actuator dependency in pom.xml

Comment: no I don't have actuator dependency in pim.xml

Comment: please dont use custom security and instead implement JWT using the built in features of spring security https://thomasandolf.medium.com/spring-security-jwts-getting-started-ebdb4e4f1dd1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for it, the 404 not found error was because I didn't annotated field in one of my model class with @Id annotation. It's resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the exclude part from the @SpringBootApplication and.
Add this two lines in your application.properties file.

```
spring.security.user.name=abc
spring.security.user.password=xxx
```

Try this code for SecurityConfiguration. and remove .anyRequest().authenticated(); because you don't require that.

```
http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
//                .antMatchers("/post").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/post","/deleteComment/**", "/deletePost/**", "/updateComment/**",
                        "/updateCommentPage/**", "/updatePostPage/**","/api/draft/**","/api/post/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER","ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/","/api","/api/addComment/**","/api/viewPost/**").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and().httpBasic().and()
                .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success").permitAll();
```

Comment: I tried as mentioned by you. But I am getting **401 unauthorized** for all my api's even though I have mentioned above configuration in my SecurityConfiguration class.

Comment: Can you share you SecuritConfiguration file ?

Comment: Not able to share my SecurityConfiguration file due to stackoverflow policies (file too long), but I am extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class and overriding configure method.

Comment: ok just try to remove anyrequest().authenticated() and try to implement the code like mine

Comment: to generalize the issue, when I am disabling spring security by any method either by using exclude annotation in main class or as mentioned by you adding few parameters in app.properties, I am getting **404 not found** in postman response for all apis, and when I am enabling spring security it is giving **401 unauthorized** in postman response

Comment: Also I am confused if the 404 not found I am getting is really because I am disabling spring security !!

Answer (score 0):

Your setup actually requires authentication - `.anyRequest().authenticated();` You can do permit all for any request, that should do it.

```
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
```